# How can I create an object mapping from an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

i am stumbling onto something that should be easy, yet i can't seem to be able to do it.

i have an array of string, and i want to map over it to create an object like so :

```js
const monthesList = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may']

const myState = monthesList.map(month => (
    month: {selected: false, year: 2022}
    )
  )
```

what i want is to get the following object :

```js
myState ={
  january:{ 
    selected: false,
    year: 2022
  },
  february:{ 
    selected: false,
    year: 2022
  },
  march:{ 
    selected: false,
    year: 2022
  },
  april:{ 
    selected: false,
    year: 2022
  },
  may:{ 
    selected: false,
    year: 2022
  },
}
```

Edit:
i just found the way :

```js
const myState = monthesList.map(month => (
    {[month] : {
      selected: false,
      year: 2022
    }}
    )
  )
```

just need to make an object out of it, shouldn't be too hard

Comment: yes you're right, i know but it's not what was bothering me, i can easliy transfomr the array to an object

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to match your examples to your code; is it `selected` or `sleected`? Is it `true` or `false`?

Comment: You still have `selected: true` in your first code snippet and `false` everywhere else

Comment: sorry about that, it's fixed !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method returns an array, but the output that you're after is an object. You need something that can convert an array of key-value pairs (ie: `[key, value]`) to an object. For this, we have the [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method that takes an array of key-value pairs, and from it, constructs an object like so:

```js
const monthesList = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may'];

const myState = Object.fromEntries(monthesList.map(month => [
  month, {selected: false, year: 2022}
]));
console.log(myState);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate an array of arrays with the values in each internal array being the month name and object; then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert that into your desired object:

```js
const monthesList = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may']

const myState = Object.fromEntries(
  monthesList.map(m => [m, {selected: false, year: 2022}])
)

console.log(myState)
```

Comment: Small fyi: `selected` should be `false`.

Comment: It should also be `sleected` according to OP's example 

Comment: @Andy Ironically I copied it from OPs code...

Comment: @Phil well, the spelling has been corrected but there's still one `true` and one `false` in the question's code... perhaps I should put in a non-binary value instead :)

Comment: [`FileNotFound`](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/what_is_truth_0x3f_)

Comment: @Phil ROTFL!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`map` will only return an array. Your expected output is an object. There's no need to over-complicate things - use [a simple loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) instead.

```js
const list = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may'];

const myState = {};

for (const month of list) {
  myState[month] = { selected: false, year: 2022 };
}

console.log(myState);
```